# python - IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1

Tags: python, lucene, syntax-error

I'm trying to run the following code. Unfortunately, I get an error that I'm not able to solve myself yet.

```
import numpy as np
import random

def reallyrandom(arg1, arg2, arg3):
    
    int1=int(arg1)
    int2=int(arg2)
    int3=int(arg3)

    np.random.seed(42)

    x=np.random.randint(0,10, size=int1)
    print(x)
    print(x.shape)
    y=x*int2
    print(y)
    print(y.shape)
    z=y[int3]
    print(z)
    

    print(f"Your random value is {z}")

reallyrandom(1,2,9)
```

Error:

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15232/4039400629.py in <module>
     23 
     24 #reallyrandom(59,2,7)
---> 25 reallyrandom(1,2,9)

~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_15232/4039400629.py in reallyrandom(arg1, arg2, arg3)
     16     print(y)
     17     print(y.shape)
---> 18     z=y[int3]
     19     #print(z)
     20 

IndexError: index 9 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

The problem seems to start in defining value z in `line z=y[int3]`
I have no idea how to solve it. Could someone explain what I'm doing wrong?
I found on the internet that it is an index error?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line `z = y[int3]` is attempting to get the 9th value from the array `y` (because the index `int3` is 9), but there's only one value in the array. This line:

```
x = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=int1)
```

is creating an array with only one random value in it (because the value of `int1` is 1). If you want to create an array of 10 random numbers, for example, use:

```
x = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=10)
```

Alternatively, you can use some other variable for `size`, but it needs to be larger than the index you pass in `z = y[int3]` or you'll get the same `IndexError`.